# Example of a hardness-of-approximation proof which improves the approximation factor?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, approximation-algorithms, approximation-hardness

Are there any examples of hardness-of-approximation reductions where we get a better hardness bound for the problem we've reduced to than the problem we've reduced from? In the examples I've seen so far, the bound is usually degraded in the reduction.

Comment: A lot of reductions amplify hardness by toying with the objective function. For example, Min Circuit SAT (given a Boolean circuit, what is the smallest hamming-weight input that evaluates to true) is NP-hard because it can encode min vertex cover. This gives a small hardness factor of ~2. So it's hard to distinguish instances that can be solved with weight a=f(n) from those with weight 1.5a. But now we can reduce from this circuit sat instance by making the circuit that accepts either solutions to the original CSAT instance of weight <= a, or anything of weight > n/2, for $\omega(1)$ hardness.

Comment: @YonatanN That's a great example. I would accept it as an answer if you want to copy paste it.